# Crystal reports remove variable substrings

Tags: html, crystal-reports

I am trying to remove HTML style tags from my Crystal report text. I have data like the below:

```
<span style="font-size:small;">hello world</span><span style="font-size:12.0pt;line-height:115%;">hello again world</span><p style="text-decoration:underline;">hello once again</p>
```

I want the result to be:

```
<span>hello world</span><span>hello again world</span><p>hello once again</p>
```

I've used:

```
replace({IncidentNarrative.text},ExtractString(Totext({IncidentNarrative.text}),"<span ",">"),"")
replace({IncidentNarrative.text},ExtractString(Totext({IncidentNarrative.text}),"<p ",">"),"")
```

But this will only remove the first instance of the `span` or `p`. It does not look for all instances of the `span` or `p`. I've tried FOR loops and extracting the sub-strings into arrays, but always run into problems.

Comment: what is your language for replace? is it c#?

Comment: its the default crystal syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following formula looks for the term `style=` and removes it and everything between `style=` to the next occurence of `>`:

```
StringVar output := {IncidentNarrative.text};

While InStr(output, " style=")>0 And InStr(InStr(output, " style=")+7, output, ">")>0 Do
(
    output := Left(output, InStr(output, " style=")-1) &
                Mid(output, InStr(InStr(output, " style=")+7, output, ">"))
);

output;
```

Comment: When I try that it gives me a "Start position is less than 1 or not an integer." And highlights the MID formula. I tried to adjust the instr within the MID with no improvement, same error.

Comment: That means there are values that are missing a closing `>` after `style=`. I've edited the answer and added an additional check to the formula.

Comment: Excellent! That did it.